# What is meant when light is described as 'metallic'?

Tags: meaning

I have seen this used quite a few times in novels. Two examples are:

> Molasses buckets appeared from nowhere, and the CEILING DANCED WITH METALLIC LIGHT.
>
> -*To Kill a Mockingbird*

> Aureliano...sitting against the metallic and quivering light from the window...
>
> -*One Hundred Years of Solitude*

I am thinking that it means the light glows as if reflected against a metallic surface. Is this it? Are there any underlying meanings?

Comment: The second example is from *Cien años de soledad,* so may be a literal translation of a Spanish idiom... luz metálica y temblorosa

Comment: I think a question on this line might be better asked on [Literature.se] The meaning of "metallic" is found in a dictionary.  The interpretation in a literary context is not on topic

Answer (score 1):

If you look in a [dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/metallic) you will find that *metallic* means having the characteristics of metal. It would usually be applied to the light reflected from a surface. There is no particular hidden meaning here.